# YouTube pause, play & stop not working

Tags: javascript, php, youtube

I want to play my video on any `play anchor <a> tag` on my page, 
If it's in pause state then it must start play. If it's in play state then after click on play it must start playing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api">  </script>
<script>
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {player = new YT.Player('player');}
</script>

<iframe id="player" style="position: relative; height: 220px; width: 400px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YL_OcLayJPg?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe><br>

<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player.playVideo(); return false">play</a><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player.pauseVideo(); return false">pause</a>
```

It's work in HTML page on localhost but not on server in PHP file.

It's not working on server.

Comment: Have you invoked/called `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` ?

Comment: You need to bind `play/pause` events after `onReady` event..

Comment: @RayonDabre can you tell me how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `play/pause` events must be attached inside `'onReady'` event handler in `YT.Player` initialization.

```js
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    events: {
      // call this function when player is ready to use
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady() {
  // bind events
  var playButton = document.getElementById("play");
  playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.playVideo();
  });

  var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");
  pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.pauseVideo();
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<iframe id="player" style="position: relative; height: 220px; width: 400px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YL_OcLayJPg?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
<br>

<a href="javascript: void(0)" id='play'>play</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" id='pause'>pause</a>
```

**Note:** You could just link to it in a `<script>`, but all their documentation shows loading it `async style`, which is always good for third-party scripts.

```js
// Inject YouTube API script
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```